# How to see path of apache-parquet(cpp) in ubuntu(i installed it)?

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I am unable to view the installation.How to see path of parquet(c++) where it's installed?

Comment: How did you install it? Using apt or some kind of installer script?

Comment: i referred these websites: [https://arrow.apache.org/install/],
[https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/cpp/building.html],
[https://colinsblog.net/2018-06-23-notes-on-writing-and-reading-parquet-files-in-c-plus-plus/]

Comment: If you did `make install`, it should have installed headers in `/usr/local/include` and libraries in `/usr/local/lib`